# Convert tupel array into 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

The output from the method `detect_keypoints(imagename, threshold)` returns an `ndarray`, which looks like this:

```
[[131 326   1   0]
 [135 281   1   0]
 [159 405   1   0]]
```

Basically there's more data, but I'll keep it simple for this question. Just by this array, I'm not able to get certain columns, what is my actual goal. It keeps tellung me, that the above `ndarray` a tuple is and hence I can't access any value of it. So, I'm trying to convert the `ndarray` into a 2D array to read all integers of each array.

**My implementation so far:**

After research I implemented this one for converting:

```
def keypoints2D(imagename, threshold):
    keypoints = detect_keypoints(imagename, threshold) 
    keypoints = np.array(keypoints)
    lst = [list(i) for i in keypoints]
    print(lst)
    keypoints_lst = lst[:, 0]
    print(keypoints_lst)
    return lst
```

Doing so, I'll get

```
[[array([131, 326,   1,   0]), array([135, 281,   1,   0]), array([159, 405,   1,   0])]]
```

Even though, I'd like to get by converting something like this:

```
[[131, 326,   1,   0]
 [135, 281,   1,   0]
 [159, 405,   1,   0]]
```

If I try to get a certain column, it keeps telling me there's a exception in `keypoints_lst = lst[:, 0]`:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

In terms of the exception the return value is still a tuple. How can I change/convert it into a proper 2D array? Nevertheless the output of the `ndarray` should stay like this.

Comment: I think you are accessing the elements wrongly after the conversion

Comment: @bigbounty what will be the correct way to do this?

Comment: "*It keeps tellung me, that the above ndarray a tuple*" - Please copy-paste the precise error message. Fetching a column from that array [works for me](https://ideone.com/tXfkaz).

Answer (score 1):

```
[[131 326   1   0]
 [135 281   1   0]
 [159 405   1   0]]
```

looks like a 2d array, which can simply be indexed with `arr[:,0]` for the first column, `arr[0,:]` the first row.  `arr[0,1]` is actually `arr[(0,1)]`.  Arrays take a tuple of indices.

Arrays display with the commas, lists with.

Your conversion looks like a nested list with array elements.  Lists don't accept the multidimensional indexing (tuples).

```
alist[0]    # first element
alist[0][1]   # element of the first sublist
```

---

```
keypoints = np.array(keypoints)
lst = [list(i) for i in keypoints]
```

I don't know what the original `keypoints` (from `detect_keypoints`). But the `lst` line is creating a list of lists.

---

If I start with the nested list:

```
In [183]: target=[[131, 326,   1,   0],
     ...:  [135, 281,   1,   0],
     ...:  [159, 405,   1,   0]]
     ...: 
In [184]: target
Out[184]: [[131, 326, 1, 0], [135, 281, 1, 0], [159, 405, 1, 0]]
```

I can make a 2d array, which displays as your first item:

```
In [185]: arr = np.array(target)
In [186]: arr
Out[186]: 
array([[131, 326,   1,   0],
       [135, 281,   1,   0],
       [159, 405,   1,   0]])
In [187]: print(arr)
[[131 326   1   0]
 [135 281   1   0]
 [159 405   1   0]]
```

That is easily indexed by column

Simply passing that through your list comprehension produces:

```
In [190]: [list(i) for i in arr]
Out[190]: [[131, 326, 1, 0], [135, 281, 1, 0], [159, 405, 1, 0]]
```

`tolist` does the same thing:

```
In [191]: arr.tolist()
Out[191]: [[131, 326, 1, 0], [135, 281, 1, 0], [159, 405, 1, 0]]
```

The fact that you get a nested list of lists of arrays indicates that there's a another level of nesting in the source.

Comment: Python keeps telling me the first one being a tuple. Hence I'm not able to access each value.

Comment: It's complaining that the indexing is a tuple, not the list.  `lst[:, 0]` is trying to index the list with a tuple, `(slice(None),0)`.   `lst` is a nested list, not a 2d array.

Comment: So that's basically my question to convert the first output into a 2D array. Therefore I should be able pick columns, which I would like to. And unfortunalty I can't access them by `arr[:,0]` and so on.

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating your `lst`.  There's some level of array nesting in the original `keypoints` that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, the output

```
[[array([131, 326,   1,   0]), array([135, 281,   1,   0]), array([159, 405,   1,   0])]]
```

looks like a list of list of 1D-numpy arrays.

So a working but a bad way would be to convert lst to numpy array or maybe dont convert it into a list in the first place. 
If you do plan to convert lst to numpy,here it goes.

```
lst = np.array(lst)
print(lst[:,:,0])#shall get you the first column
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the comma in `keypoints_lst = lst[:, 0]`. When you include the comma, Python thinks you're giving a tuple, which you can't. Now, that will get rid of the error, but `keypoints_lst = lst[:0]` will just return an empty list, which I don't think you want. Python list slicing follows the format of `mylist[start:stop:step]`. When the `start` is not provided, it defaults to `0`. So with the `stop` also being `0`, you're going to get an empty list. Change the `stop` index to being the index of the last element you want to look at, plus one.

Comment: Isn't the main issue, that I don't have a proper 2D array?

Comment: At that point, you don't have an array at all. You start with a 2D numpy array, but then you convert it to a 2D vanilla python list with the line `lst = [list(i) for i in keypoints]`. What's improper about the list at that point? How does your expectation for it differ from what it actually comes out as? What do you want your output to look like?